# "buffer size must be a multiple of element size" при загрузке файла из blob-поля в numpy-массив

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

при загрузке файла из blob-поля в numpy-массив
Получаю след. ошибку:

```
file: '<string>', line: 1
'\x16\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00,\x00]\x02\x00d[\x00\x00\x7fC\x00\x0b\x03\x00\x15\t\x00\x00TY\x00\x04\x00y\x00\x00(p\x00g\x05\x00xcW\x00\x00!h\x00c\x04\x00zzY5\x00\x00\x1a`\x00_\x03\x00|nN\x13\x00\x00\x12X\x00[\x02\x00~bD\x00\x00\x0bP\x00W\x01\x00V9\x00\x00\x03G\x00SJ.\x00\x00\x06@\x00fwG.\x00\x00\t8\x00zlD.\x00\x00\x0c0\x00`A.\x00\x00\x0f(\x00U>.\x00\x00\x12 \x00I;-\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00W7&\x00\x00\x10\x00e2\x1f\x00\x00\x08\x00t-\x17\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x10\x00\x00\x0c#\x08\x00\x00\x01%\x19\x00\x00\'+\x00\x00)<\x00\x00+N\x00\x00s-`\x00\x00s*G\x00\x00s\'.\x00\x00r#\x14\x00\x00r\x01\x00 \x00\x00q\x03\x00\x1c\x00\x00\x05\x00#\x00\x00\x07\x00*\x11\x00\x00\t\x00\x021\x07)\x00\x00"\x0b\x00\x158\x14A\x00\x00O\r\x00(?!Y\x00\x00F\x0b\x00>92?\x00\x00<\x08\x00T3C$\x00\x002\x06\x00j\t-T\n'
buffer size must be a multiple of element size
```

получение файла:

```
o = cursor.execute('select file from T limit 1;').fetchone()
np.frombuffer(o, dtype=np.int16)
```

Comment: а как именно вы загружаете, мы сами должны догадаться?

Comment: np.frombuffer(o, dtype=np.int16)